# Embedding a remote Python shell in an application

Tags: python, networking

You can embed the [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/) shell inside of your application so that it launches the shell in the foreground.  Is there a way to embed a telnet server in a python app so that you can telnet to a certain port and launch a remote IPython shell?

Any tips for redirecting the input/output streams for IPython or how to hook it up to a telnet server library or recommendations for other libraries that could be used to implement this are much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Python includes a [telnet client](http://www.python.org/doc/lib/module-telnetlib.html), but not a telnet server.  You can implement a telnet server using [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com).  [Here's an example](http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2004-August/008335.html).  As for hooking these things together, that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Use Twisted Manhole. Docs are a bit lacking, but it's easy enough to set up a telnet-based remote server and it comes with a GTK-based GUI.

- [Main Twisted site](http://twistedmatrix.com/)
- [twisted.manhole API docs](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.manhole.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should base your server class on the [`SocketServer`](http://www.python.org/doc/lib/module-SocketServer.html) class from the standard library.  You'll need to write a `RequestHandler` to read and echo input but a lot of the heavy lifting is already done for you.

You can use the [`ThreadingMixIn`](http://docs.python.org/lib/node632.html) to make the server multi-threaded very easily.

Comment: I believe the better practice is to use "select" instead of threading on a server.  http://ilab.cs.byu.edu/python/select/echoserver.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use xmlrpc namespace